# connecting two table with id

Tags: c#

I need to create two tables programmatically with c# and those tables will have some columns and one of them is the on ID. The ID needs to be a counter that starts at 1 and always adds 1 for each row and that ID must be foreign key on the second table. How can I do it? I've already searched on internet but didnt found antything conclusive.

Comment: this is an incredibly vague question but the answer is select stuff where id1=id2 ..

Comment: I need to create the table, not to select from it. I can try to help you understanding my question, what didnt you understand?

Comment: If you are adding table(s) on in SQL it is probably easier to just manually create the tables instead of doing it in c# code.  You can add the tables directly in SQL using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) which comes with SQL Server, or add tables in VS using Menu Data.

Comment: Do you need c# DataTables or Sql tables in a DB? What is your DBMS?

Comment: More detail would help. You can use a CREATE TABLE statement to create a table and make the ID an identity column to get the behaviour you want. From C# can just use SqlCommand class to execute arbitrary SQL statements. This is assuming that you are using SQL Server and you aren't using an ORM like Entity Framework

Comment: It depends on the database you are using:  `auto_increment`, `identity`, `serial`, `generated always as` as various syntaxes.

Comment: @jdweng but I cant do it manually, it must be done with c#

Comment: @serg I need to create table inside a sql database. what do you mean by dbms?

Comment: @RichardMatheson how can I help you?

Comment: DBMS : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database As @GordonLinoff said, different DBMSes do the things in a different way.

Comment: @Serg Ok, I got it. But no, I'm just using c#

Comment: Then you may wish to drop sql tag if no sql DBMS must be connected

Comment: @Serg thanks, I've removed it

Comment: Why do you need to do with c#?  You can create a schema to configure the server.

Comment: @jdweng I must do it programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class DataStack1
{
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string somedata { get; set; }
}
public class DataStack2
{
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int DataStack1id { get; set; }
    public DataStack1 DataStack1 { get; set; }
    public string somedata { get; set; }
}
```

When you create their DBSets, Entity Framework will recognize this relation.
To create their DBSets, use the following code:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<DataStack1> DataStack1 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DataStack2> DataStack2 { get; set; }
}
```

Use the following code to access your tables:

```
using (var dataset = new DataContext())
{
    var Data = dataset.DataStack1.ToList();
}
```

You can add the following connection string to your App.config file:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Data.mdf;Initial Catalog=Data-Project;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a table A that has a relation to another table B.
So in table B will be a column with foreign key pointing to the ID of table A.

Table A

```
  ID          Column1     Column1  . . . 
   1          name1       value1
   2          nam2        value2
```

Table B

```
  ID          Column1    Column2   table_A_id  . . . 
   1          name1      value1       1
   2          name2      value1       1
   3          name3      value1       2
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable table1 =new DataTable();  
DataColumn autoIncrement=new DataColumn("AutoIncrement",typeof(System.Int32));   
table1.Columns.Add(autoIncrement);
autoIncrement.AutoIncrement=true;
autoIncrement.AutoIncrementSeed=1;
autoIncrement.ReadOnly =true;






DataTable dtEmployee = getEmployeeRecords();  
DataTable dtDepartment = getDepartmentRecords();  


DataColumn obj_ParentDepartmentID, obj_ChildDepartmentID;  
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(dtDepartment);
ds.Tables.Add(dtEmployee);
obj_ParentDepartmentID = ds.Tables["Department"].Columns["DeptID"];
obj_ChildDepartmentID = ds.Tables["Employee"].Columns["DeptID"];


dtEmployee.Columns.Add("DepartmentName");
DataRelation obj_DataRelation = new DataRelation("dept_reln", obj_ParentDepartmentID, obj_ChildDepartmentID);
ds.Relations.Add(obj_DataRelation);



foreach (DataRow dr_Employee in ds.Tables["Employee"].Rows)   
{

DataRow dr_Department = dr_Employee.GetParentRow(obj_DataRelation);     
dr_Employee["DepartmentName"] = dr_Department["DeptName"];    

}
DataTable dtResult = ds.Tables["Employee"].DefaultView.ToTable(false, "EmployeeID", "EmployeeName", "FatherName", "DepartmentName");
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion